# Angular 5 best way to disabled the formControlName

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-reactive-forms

**Component TS**

```
checkStatus(){
    return this.editProspectMode;
}
return this.fb.group({
    prospect_pref_name: [{value: 'Nancy', disabled: this.checkStatus()}],
});
```

**Component HTML**

```
<input id="prospect_pref_name" type="text" formControlName="prospect_pref_name" [readonly]="!editProspectMode">
```

I want to make all form fields read-only when the form is on view mode

Answer (score 2):

You can disable a field something like this in your **TS**

```
 this.form = this.fb.group({
      fulName: [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
      userLogin: new FormControl({value: '', disabled: false}, Validators.required),
    });
```

If you want to change its property, like enable you can do something like this.

```
 this.form.controls.userLogin.enable();
```

**EDIT**

if you want to disable the entire form you can use

```
this.formGroup.disable();
```

Comment: Can we do this in form level .?

Comment: Yes sure you can do. Checkout the docs https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup `this.formGroup.disable();`

Answer (score 1):

Add `<fieldset [disabled]="editProspectMode">` in your from. 
eg

```html
<form>
  <fieldset [disabled]="editProspectMode">
    //YOUR INPUT FIELDS GOES HERE 
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Here is the working fiddle, [Disable Form on click](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hnr19g?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Hope this helps!